# Can we escape this [backslash]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

<sup>Previously titled "Yoink-dot-adios-[backslash]-lose this tag!" [Quote reference, about 3/4 of the way down](http://www.simpsonsarchive.com/episodes/AABF20.txt)</sup>

A [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381842/burninate-the-following-tagscolon-double-underscorecomma-ampersand-back) (deleted; 10k+ only) has found out that there should be only [one tag per burninate request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)...

> **DO NOT** try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion.

... so I'm creating the burninate request for one of those tags, [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash).

Currently there are 746 questions in the [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) tag.  Its own excerpt describes at least two meanings:

> The backslash character \ (not to be confused with slash /) is used in many languages to quote the next character, i.e. to make it lose its special meaning. It is also the directory separator in file paths under DOS and Windows.

The body goes on to describe several more: starting a command in LaTex, introducing a lambda in Haskell.

Let's evaluate this tag according to the burnination criteria.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   It only partially describes the contents of the questions, due to its ambiguity.  Additional context is required to ascertain the specific meaning.  It appears to be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   It may be on topic, but by itself it doesn't narrow down the specific meaning enough; it's too ambiguous by itself.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   Yes, it adds some information to the post, but not enough to be meaningful, again, due to ambiguity.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No, as has been established.

There is only one question that is tagged both [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) and [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash), and it has nothing to do with a Haskell lambda.  There are only 4 questions that are tagged both [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) and [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash).  There are only 27 questions that are tagged both [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path) and [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash).  There are 126 questions that are tagged both [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping) and [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash).

It may be useful to re-tag some of these questions according to those other existing tags:

- Some questions are likely to have [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) removed, especially if it already has another tag such as [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path) or [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping).
- Other questions may need [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) replaced with the appropriate tag.
- Other questions may only happen to have a backslash in the code in question, which is not enough reason to have the tag, which would seem to indicate that it should simply be removed.

This burninate request contains some retagging also, to at least [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping) or [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path).

Comment: I have to disagree with this request. Sure, backslash has different uses in different contexts, but for the vast majority of cases, backslash is used as an escape character. Looking that the first few posts using the tag, it looks like it's used in that context.

Comment: @NickVitha It most certainly is used in the escape character context, but it is also used for other purposes, as I have already stated.  If a post were to be tagged _only_ [backslash], would you know what it's about without any other knowledge?  No.

Comment: well I would know it's about the character "\" and that it has various uses in different contexts, but I'd say it's the equivalent of, for instance, the database or list tags. If we decide to burninate the backslash tag, you might as well burninate 90% of the tags on the site.

Comment: @NickVitha "90% of the tags on the site"?  On what basis did you conclude that?  Also, the [backslash] tag doesn't tell you know enough information on what the question is about.  Let's go back to the hypothetical question with only a [backslash] tag.  Hmm... A backslash tag?  What is the question about?  Is it part of an escape character?  A Windows pathname?  Something else?  It's not descriptive enough, which is why it's a "meta tag".

Comment: It's not even worth arguing over this. At worst it's a meta tag that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to merge the tag with [escaping] or split into something like [backslash (escape character)] and [backslash (path separator)]. In its current form, I don't see how this tag is any more useful than a [letter A] or a [Unicode 0x0DE7] tag.